# Spark-submit issue loading classes

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hortonworks-data-platform, spark-submit

I'm using HDP 2.6. I downloaded newest version of Spark (2.2.1) and using `spark-submit` I'm trying to run my jar (build with same version of Spark as assembly). However, I'm getting error:

```
Class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RequestHedgingRMFailoverProxyProvider not found
```

my `$HADOOP_CONF_DIR` is `/etc/hadoop/conf` which is link to `/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf`
my `yarn-site.xml` in `yarn.application.classpath` contains entry: `/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-yarn-client/*` This directory contains jar `hadoop-yarn-common.jar` which contains class `org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RequestHedgingRMFailoverProxyProvider` . That is why don't understand what is going.

I did this checks base on suggestions in:
[link 1](https://community.hortonworks.com/content/supportkb/150154/errorjavalangclassnotfoundexception-class-orgapach.html)
[link 2](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/113106/class-orgapachehadoopyarnclientrequesthedgingrmfai.html)
Bellow full stacktrace if usefull:

```
[root@omm101 bin]# pwd
/opt/spark_2.2.1/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/bin
[root@omm101 bin]# echo $HADOOP_CONF_DIR
/etc/hadoop/conf
[root@omm101 bin]# ./spark-submit --class net.atos.ooredooom.reportengine.trareport.TraReport --master yarn --deploy-mode client --num-executors 18 --executor-cores 5 --executor-memory 15g --driver-memory 1g /root/jars/report-compute-engine.jar
18/01/25 17:22:50 INFO spark.SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.2.1
18/01/25 17:22:50 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
18/01/25 17:22:51 INFO spark.SparkContext: Submitted application: TRA-Report
18/01/25 17:22:51 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: root
18/01/25 17:22:51 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: root
18/01/25 17:22:51 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to:
18/01/25 17:22:51 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to:
18/01/25 17:22:51 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(root); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(root); groups with modify permissions: Set()
18/01/25 17:22:51 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 41613.
18/01/25 17:22:51 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
18/01/25 17:22:51 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
18/01/25 17:22:51 INFO storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
18/01/25 17:22:51 INFO storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
18/01/25 17:22:51 INFO storage.DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-27408430-08bf-4252-b320-e68e6d103154
18/01/25 17:22:51 INFO memory.MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 366.3 MB
18/01/25 17:22:51 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
18/01/25 17:22:51 INFO util.log: Logging initialized @1743ms
18/01/25 17:22:51 INFO server.Server: jetty-9.3.z-SNAPSHOT
18/01/25 17:22:51 INFO server.Server: Started @1814ms
18/01/25 17:22:51 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Started ServerConnector@c835d12{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4040}
18/01/25 17:22:51 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
18/01/25 17:22:51 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@2a2bb0eb{/jobs,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 17:22:51 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@58783f6c{/jobs/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 17:22:51 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@512d92b{/jobs/job,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 17:22:51 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1bc53649{/jobs/job/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 17:22:51 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@47d93e0d{/stages,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 17:22:51 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@751e664e{/stages/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 17:22:51 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@182b435b{/stages/stage,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 17:22:51 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3704122f{/stages/stage/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 17:22:51 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@60afd40d{/stages/pool,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 17:22:51 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3f2049b6{/stages/pool/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 17:22:51 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@ea27e34{/storage,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 17:22:51 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@e72dba7{/storage/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 17:22:51 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1dfd5f51{/storage/rdd,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 17:22:51 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@24855019{/storage/rdd/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 17:22:51 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@4d4d8fcf{/environment,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 17:22:51 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6f0628de{/environment/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 17:22:51 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1e392345{/executors,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 17:22:51 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@4ced35ed{/executors/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 17:22:51 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@7bd69e82{/executors/threadDump,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 17:22:51 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@51b01960{/executors/threadDump/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 17:22:51 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@27dc79f7{/static,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 17:22:51 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@7674a051{/,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 17:22:51 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6754ef00{/api,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 17:22:51 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3301500b{/jobs/job/kill,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 17:22:51 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@15deb1dc{/stages/stage/kill,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 17:22:51 INFO ui.SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://10.4.110.24:4040
18/01/25 17:22:51 INFO spark.SparkContext: Added JAR file:/root/jars/report-compute-engine.jar at spark://10.4.110.24:41613/jars/report-compute-engine.jar with timestamp 1516886571716
18/01/25 17:22:52 WARN shortcircuit.DomainSocketFactory: The short-circuit local reads feature cannot be used because libhadoop cannot be loaded.
18/01/25 17:22:52 INFO impl.TimelineClientImpl: Timeline service address: http://omm103.in.nawras.com.om:8188/ws/v1/timeline/
18/01/25 17:22:52 INFO service.AbstractService: Service org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl failed in state STARTED; cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RequestHedgingRMFailoverProxyProvider not found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RequestHedgingRMFailoverProxyProvider not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2227)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy.createRMFailoverProxyProvider(RMProxy.java:161)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy.createRMProxy(RMProxy.java:94)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.ClientRMProxy.createRMProxy(ClientRMProxy.java:72)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl.serviceStart(YarnClientImpl.java:187)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.submitApplication(Client.scala:153)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:173)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:509)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2516)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:918)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:910)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:910)
        at net.atos.ooredooom.reportengine.trareport.TraReport$.main(TraReport.scala:14)
        at net.atos.ooredooom.reportengine.trareport.TraReport.main(TraReport.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:775)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RequestHedgingRMFailoverProxyProvider not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2195)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2219)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RequestHedgingRMFailoverProxyProvider not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2101)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2193)
        ... 26 more
18/01/25 17:22:52 ERROR spark.SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RequestHedgingRMFailoverProxyProvider not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2227)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy.createRMFailoverProxyProvider(RMProxy.java:161)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy.createRMProxy(RMProxy.java:94)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.ClientRMProxy.createRMProxy(ClientRMProxy.java:72)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl.serviceStart(YarnClientImpl.java:187)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.submitApplication(Client.scala:153)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:173)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:509)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2516)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:918)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:910)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:910)
        at net.atos.ooredooom.reportengine.trareport.TraReport$.main(TraReport.scala:14)
        at net.atos.ooredooom.reportengine.trareport.TraReport.main(TraReport.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:775)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RequestHedgingRMFailoverProxyProvider not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2195)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2219)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RequestHedgingRMFailoverProxyProvider not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2101)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2193)
        ... 26 more
18/01/25 17:22:52 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Stopped Spark@c835d12{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4040}
18/01/25 17:22:52 INFO ui.SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://10.4.110.24:4040
18/01/25 17:22:52 WARN cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Attempted to request executors before the AM has registered!
18/01/25 17:22:52 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Stopped
18/01/25 17:22:52 INFO spark.MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
18/01/25 17:22:52 INFO memory.MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
18/01/25 17:22:52 INFO storage.BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
18/01/25 17:22:52 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
18/01/25 17:22:52 WARN metrics.MetricsSystem: Stopping a MetricsSystem that is not running
18/01/25 17:22:52 INFO scheduler.OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
18/01/25 17:22:52 INFO spark.SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RequestHedgingRMFailoverProxyProvider not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2227)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy.createRMFailoverProxyProvider(RMProxy.java:161)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy.createRMProxy(RMProxy.java:94)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.ClientRMProxy.createRMProxy(ClientRMProxy.java:72)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl.serviceStart(YarnClientImpl.java:187)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.submitApplication(Client.scala:153)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:173)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:509)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2516)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:918)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:910)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:910)
        at net.atos.ooredooom.reportengine.trareport.TraReport$.main(TraReport.scala:14)
        at net.atos.ooredooom.reportengine.trareport.TraReport.main(TraReport.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:775)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RequestHedgingRMFailoverProxyProvider not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2195)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2219)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RequestHedgingRMFailoverProxyProvider not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2101)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2193)
        ... 26 more
18/01/25 17:22:52 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
18/01/25 17:22:52 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-8ea65e11-e6d7-480c-874b-e35071fa6d7f
```

Any support/hint would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**
Due to lack of better ideas, to `spark-submit` I added `--jars /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-yarn-client/hadoop-yarn-common-2.7.3.2.6.1.0-129.jar` and this caused:`IllegalAccessError`: tried to access method `org.apache.hadoop.yarn.clientRMFailoverProxyProvider.getProxyInternal()`

when this didn't worked I tried to put `hadoop-yarn-common-2.7.3.2.6.1.0-129.jar` into `.../<spark_dir>/jars`
And I got the same result.

So basically the question is why spark is not using hdp jars. And should it use that (because I see this `IllegalAccessError` when I force using this lib). In Spark 2.2.1 there is a jar `hadoop-yarn-common-2.7.3.jar` but this jar doesn't contain `RequestHedgingRMFailoverProxyProvider` (maybe HDP specific?)

Comment: I assume the included HDP Spark works fine?

Comment: Did you download that on the same server that hadoop is already on? If so, you needed the Spark download that doesn't include its own Hadoop

Comment: I just testes same with spark-2.2.1-bin-without-hadoop.tgz. When I tried to execute spark-submit I immediately got: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream` . Moreover, same happens while executing `spark-shell`. But earlier (with Spark with prebuilded hadoop) at least I were able to start spark-shell and perform some actions on HDFS.

Comment: You still need to configure Spark to know where `HADOOP_HOME` , or the `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` is located

Answer (score 1):

HDP default config uses `org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RequestHedgingRMFailoverProxyProvider` for the implementation. however, Spark does not pack with this impl. but the other one called `ConfiguredRMFailoverProxyProvider`. both of them implement interface `RMFailoverProxyProvider`. (refer to this doc: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/client/RMFailoverProxyProvider.html)

so in order to fix this, just follow this instruction and change the config on HDP. https://community.hortonworks.com/content/supportkb/178800/errorclass-orgapachehadoopyarnclientrequesthedging.html